# Artists similar to Blanck Mass

Tags: electronic-music, similar-artists

I'm looking for artists/albums/songs specifically similar to Blanck Mass albums "Dumb Flesh" (especially the song "Dead Format"), "World Eater", (to a slightly lesser extent) "Animated Violence Mild" and the single "D7-D5".

Blanck Mass composes electronic music I find very difficult to classify. As a huge electronic music fan I still find nothing quite like it. Exploring the genres typically associated with him  (electro-industrial, IDM) I would find music that sounds very little like it. The sound I would describe as extremely thick, textured, heavily layered, noisy, experimental and, for the lack of a better word, large.

Some songs I've found that sort of scratch the same itch:

- Ben Frost - Nolan
- Oneohtrix Point Never - Sticky Drama
- Tim Hecker - Where Shadows Make Shadows
- 65daysofstatic - Dance Parties [Mechanised]

And some of the songs by Benjamin's other band Fuck Buttons.

But I'm looking for more! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the music and artist's description on Wikipedia he seems to be a combination of post-rock, IDM, and noise. A bit tricky. Here would be my suggestions to look into.

**IDM**

Autechre ([Second Bad Vibel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6zT3kVtpHc), [Gantz Graf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ev3vENli7wQ), [plyPhon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsNbUlyERV0), [Fleure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Je6NChw3LiY), [Bladeroles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiRLb8AYgIc))
Amon Tobin ([Triple Science](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_byFKB19pc))
Two Fingers ([Razorback](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGOdU9Yd_74))

**Noise**

Des Esseintes ([Due](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3B3Q1j3aXDo), [King of the Jungle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugueH6qaEfY))

**Post-rock**

World's End Girlfriend ([Requiem remix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdZm_Rzet1s), [Caroling Hellwalker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBcTQgFj1hg))

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [music-map](https://www.music-map.com/). You enter a band you like, and it suggests others you also might like. For example, for Blanck Mass [it suggests](https://www.music-map.com/blanck+mass) [Roly Porter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=su4MpkVpwlw) and [Emptyset](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_o0bgCaHZzw), among many others. For [Ben Frost](https://www.music-map.com/ben+frost) it suggests [Kreng](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNoZwVR3V8s) as well as Roly Porter again, plus ....

Comment: Roly Porter is dark ambient which sounds nothing like BM so I wonder where they get the connection.